Advice on web scraping techniques and how to implement for contact details
I made a webscraping script which finds contact details of housing companies using regex and selenium, I have no experience with other web scraping tools and I am open to all crtitisim and suggestions.
I need help more consistantly finding correct details, Also if anyone has any regex expressions that work well for UK phone numbers.
type hfrom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 

# Path to the extension .crx file
extension_path = 'xxx'
chromedriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

# Verify the extension file exists
if not os.path.exists(extension_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"The extension file at {extension_path} does not exist.")

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path)

# Initialize ChromeDriver with the extension
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Set page load timeout
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)

# Regular expressions
phone_regex = re.compile(
    r'\+44\s?\d{4}\s?\d{6}|\(?0\d{4}\)?\d{3}\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?\d{3}\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{2}\)?\d{4}\s?\d{4}'
)
email_regex = re.compile(
    r'[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}'
)

def locate_contact():
    try:

        contact_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Contact us') or contains(text(), 'Contact') or contains(text(), 'Get in touch')]")
        print("Contact us link found")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Couldn't find a contact page: {e}")
        return

def get_contact():
    page_source = driver.page_source

    phone_numbers = phone_regex.findall(page_source)
    emails = email_regex.findall(page_source)

    phone_numbers = [num for num in phone_numbers if len(num) > 6 and len(num) < 15]
    phone_numbers = phone_numbers[:3]
    phone_numbers = list(set(phone_numbers))

    emails = emails[:3]
    emails = list(set(emails))

    main_page_source = driver.page_source
    phone_numbers, emails = retry_missing_details(driver, phone_numbers, emails, main_page_source)

    housing_name = driver.title[:53]
    housing_name = housing_name.replace(',', '|')
    housing_name = housing_name.replace('-', '|')

    print(housing_name)
    print(f"Found emails: {emails}")
    print(f"Found phone numbers: {phone_numbers}")
    print('----------------------------------------------')

    all_data.append([housing_name, ', '.join(emails), ', '.join(phone_numbers)])


def retry_missing_details(driver, phone_numbers, emails, main_page_source):
    if not phone_numbers or not emails:
        print("Retrying main page for missing details")
        new_phone_numbers = phone_regex.findall(main_page_source)
        new_emails = email_regex.findall(main_page_source)

        new_phone_numbers = [num for num in new_phone_numbers if len(num) > 6 and len(num) < 15]
        new_phone_numbers = list(set(new_phone_numbers))

        new_emails = list(set(new_emails))

        if not phone_numbers:
            phone_numbers = new_phone_numbers[:3]
        if not emails:
            emails = new_emails[:3]

    return phone_numbers, emails

# List to store all data
all_data = []

try:
    # Read URLs from the CSV file
    with open('housing_association_links.csv', mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip header 
        urls = [row[0] for row in reader]


    for url in urls:
        try:
            try:
                driver.get(url)

                # Wait for the page to fully load 
                WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body'))  # Change to a more specific element if needed
                )

                locate_contact()
                get_contact()

            except TimeoutException:
                print(f"Page load timed out for URL {url}. Moving to the next URL.")
                continue  # Skip to the next URL in case of a timeout

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing URL {url}: {e}")
            continue


finally:
    csv_file = "housing_associations.csv"
    with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["Housing Association Name", "Contact Email Address", "Telephone Number"])

        all_data_as_tuples = set(tuple(row) for row in all_data)
        all_data = [list(row) for row in all_data_as_tuples]

        writer.writerows(all_data)

    driver.quit()

print('done')

ere

This code does indeed work, however i am more concerned about imporving the efficiency as alot of websites will just return random strings of character that the regex considers phone numbers/emails. I was wondering if i could use another method of webscraping and then compare the results of both methods to get more accurate details. Any help is greatly appreciated.
